# Персонаж "Анны Карениной" ― Левин или Лёвин?

Tags: литература, ономастика

Смотрел я этот новый британский фильм "Анна Каренина". Который с Кирой Найтли.

Там местами есть заметная разница между словами в английском озвучивании и в русском. Поэтому я включал то русскую звуковую дорожку, то английскую. И субтитры переключал. Русские субтитры там, это как раз дословный перевод английского варианта озвучки. В общем, это не так важно. Так что коротко о главном. Вот такое отличие мне показалось интересным.

В русских субтитрах написано ― **Лёвин**. А в озвучивании (и русс., и англ.) говорят ― **Левин**. Говорят [Льэ], а не [Льо].

Как же правильно?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Сам Толстой называл своего персонажа Л**ё**вин, считая, что фамилию через "е" может носить еврейский лавочник, а не русский дворянин, но издатели заморачиваться с литерой "ё" не захотели. Сам Толстой, кстати, тоже был Лёв, а не Лев, о чём свидетельствуют прижизненные переводы классика, где он Lyoff, а также сохранившиеся аудиозаписи голоса самого Толстого.

Первый же русский чемпион мира по шахматам Александр Алехин, наоборот страдал от добавления к его фамилии лишних точек. Его дворянская фамилия вела начало не от фамильярных Алёх.

Comment: >Сам Толстой, кстати, тоже был Лёв, а не Лев, о чём свидетельствуют прижизненные переводы классика, где он Lyoff, а также сохранившиеся аудиозаписи голоса самого Толстого.

Интересно. Есть уменьшительное **Лёва**. А полное имя **Лев** через **Ё** слышать не приходилось.

Это что, такой  вариант произношения в XIX веке? Хотелось бы понять. А зверь, который царь зверей, надеюсь не через **Ё** раньше писался?.

Comment: У Пушкина где-то лёв с плов рифмуется. Лёв - это старомосковская норма произношения.

Comment: >Лёв - это старомосковская норма произношения.

В смысле не имя, а животное? Если с маленькой буквы.
А, вы изменили комментарий, и теперь написали с большой. Спасибо за добавленные стихи. Это интересно.

Comment: Имя - Лёв, не извольте сомневаться.
А вот что касается царя зверей, то тут некая непонятка. Писался-то то он через Ё, но вот как произносился - не совсем ясно. Видимо испытывал колебания.

Comment: Тут вот какая штука. В "льве" - беглая гласная. Такие слова в значительно меньшей степени подверглись "ёфикации" в XIV-XVII веках. Но в отличие от слов с ятем, где подобный закон был почти императивным (ять в Ё не переходил за исключением единичных случаев), с беглой гласной такое все-таки итногда происходило. Но зато именно это эти "неправильные" переходы более всего подверглись ре-славянизации под действием церковно-славянского.

Answer (score 3):

Лёвин. Однозначно. 
"Левиным" в те годы мог быть только еврей.
Имя же Лев, Лёва от которого должен бы произойти Левин, однозначно писалось и произносилось через Ё.

> Его дворянская фамилия вела начало от польских ляхов, а не от русских Алёх.

А он-то тут каким боком?
С ним вообще большая путаница. Я знаю эту версию про то, что он якобы настаивал на Е 
(без точек) в своей фамилии. Но достоверных источников или свидетельств так никто и не предъявил.

Comment: БСЭ для вас авторитетный источник? Ещё можно добавить, что по французски и немецки он свою фамилию писал через "е".

Comment: >БСЭ для вас авторитетный источник?  
  
Нет. Там только "официальная" версия.   

>Ещё можно добавить, что по французски и немецки он свою фамилию писал через "е".  
  
Тем более. У меня в трех паспортах - три разных написания моей фамилии. 
Это вообще даже не траслитерациия, клир.

Comment: Я про паспорта и не говорю, книги и статьи за авторством Алехина, изначально написанные им на данных языках. Сомнительно, чтобы сам носитель фамилии стал её коверкать, используя транскрипцию, вместо транслитерации.

Comment: www.e3e5.com/article.php?id=1684 вот ещё воспоминания про Алехина.

Comment: Яzz, я нащел в себе силы относительно вдумчиво прочитать эту статью. Давайте не будем тенденциозны. В ней нет ничего актуального.  
В двух словах. С оппонентов под пунктами А) Б) и В) автор требует весомых доказательств. При этом сам даже не ссылается на что-либо подобное. 
Все что сказано по сути - история про якобы сказанное Алехиным в школе. А кто-нибудь побожился, что он это слышал своими ушами?  
  
В качестве некоторой аналогии история с Константином Бальмонтом. 
Никаким источниками не фиксируется его требование к ударению на последний слог.

Comment: Но под и ж ты - во всех современных источниках БальмОнт, вопреки ранешним тенденциям. Просто кто-то решил, что французский красивше шоландского, к каковому корню и возводится фамилия, перекликаясь, кстати с именем предка другого "шлтландца" - Лермонтова.

Comment: Нашёл всё-таки ту статью на [грамоте](http://www.gramota.ru/class/istiny/istiny_7_jo/).

Вкратце, "е" не переходило в "ё" в позиции перед мягкими согласными плётка – плеть, весёлый – веселье, подённый – день, щёлка – щель, смышлёный – мышление, то же в именах собственных: Савёлово (станция) – Савелий (имя), Озёры (город) – Заозерье (село), Стёпка – Стенька, Олёна (Алёна) – Оленин (Аленин) и т. д. Соответственно и в фамилии шахматиста условий для перехода не было, там же ссылки на мемуары.